# How can I show the marker for particular location on the map using leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using the following code:

```
var cord = ["12.9791198", "77.5912997"];

// custom id for marker
var customId = Math.random();

var marker = L.marker([cord[1], cord[0]], {
  title: selectedObj.display_name,
  id: customId,
})
  .addTo(map)
  .bindPopup(selectedObj.display_name);

map.setView([cord[1], cord[0]], 8);
```

and for this i am getting error like `Uncaught TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function`

Comment: Have you defined your map? is your variable name `map` the same?

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/DSjiCTvAkYxYuZhR). Please take a bit of time to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have fixed this, variable "map" should be global variable, but it was declared as local variable. so i was not able to show the marker.

@FalkeDesign  Thanks for the response